# Git - remove specific untracked directory/file

Tags: git

I've got these untracked files. I only want to remove the public/fonts/ directory/files. The rest I want to keep.

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        public/fonts/
        public/images/favicon.png
        resources/views/vendor/
```

I only been able to find how to delete all files with these commands:

```
git clean -n (see which files will be deleted)
git clean -f (delete all files)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what do you mean with "remove"? Because removing them should be as simple as running `rm public/fonts -fR` and it has no relation to git whatsoever. If what you would like is for those files to be _ignored_, you can add patterns in `.gitignore` or in `.git/info/exclude`.

Comment: Want to remove it from untracked files. I don't need those files afterall.

Comment: I guess what you want is to ignore them so that git doesn't report them as untracked.

Comment: @eftshift0 I'm stupid. `rm public/fonts -fR` is exactly what I needed. That's what happens when you work too long, are tired, and have a brain fart. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You don't need Git to remove files that are not tracked by Git. Even more, Git doesn't provide any command to help you with this task. The reason is very simple: since they are not tracked (i.e. not in the Git repository), Git does not have any work to do. If you want to remove them then use the tools provided by the OS: `rm` on Unix or `del` on Windows or a GUI file manager and that's all. They won't appear any more in the output of `git status`.

Comment: Why is this question, which was answered in May (in the comments) suddenly getting all this unneeded attention?

Comment: @matt Because comments are not answers, so it is still marked "unanswered". Somebody stumbled on it, or an algorithm decided to show it in some results, and now you and I are here.

Answer (score 4):

`git clean` only operates where you invoke it.

So cd into that directory and clean it up.

The `git` command also has a change-directory-first option, so `git -C public/fonts clean` will remove all untracked files in and below that directory.

Answer (score -1):

I had a need to reset a subdirectory of a large repo, but didn't want to lose all of the build outputs for everything else. I realized that `git clean` was the wrong command for this. Instead, with `git status` showing no files modified, just delete the offending subdirectory, then do `git checkout -- .` to recover only the files known to git.

Comment: This sounds like a useful answer ... to a different question.